# Javascript to show next table row if current row is poulated

Tags: javascript, hide, show, selected, tablerow

I have an HTML table which is poulated by a user. The first colum in the row has a drop down box where they select an option generated by a mysql database.

This is for an orders table and the order could consist of 1 row to 72 rows. When the form loads, I only want 1 row to be displayed. When the select an option on the first row, the second row must appear. when an option is selected from the 2nd row, the 3rd row appears. and all the way to the end where row 72 only appears if an option is selected from row 71.

I hope this makes sense.

Below is my HTML table ( for 5 rows only)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)" size=1> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint1"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(2, this.value)" size=1> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint2"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(3, this.value)" size=1> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint3"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(4, this.value)" size=1> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint4"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(5, this.value)" size=1> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint5"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I know this is not a coding forum but I have searched the net for a while for a relevant example and found nothing. my javascript knowledge is very verly limited, if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Ryan Smith

Update 17 Jan 2012.

Below please find a simplified script which I cannot get to work correctly.

```
<html>
 <head>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
    {
    document.getElementById("r"+index).style.display="block" 
    }
</script> 

 </head>
 <body>


<table> 
<tr id="r1"> 
<td><select name="users" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)">  
        <OPTION VALUE=1> 
        1 
        </option> 
        <OPTION VALUE=2> 
        2
        </option>
        <OPTION VALUE=3> 
        3 
        </option> 
        </SELECT> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr id="r2" style="display:none;"> 
<td><select name="users" onchange="showUser(2, this.value)">  
        <OPTION VALUE=1> 
        1 
        </option> 
        <OPTION VALUE=2> 
        2
        </option>
        <OPTION VALUE=3> 
        3 
        </option> 
        </SELECT> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</tr> 
<tr id="r3" style="display:none;"> 
<td><select name="users" onchange="showUser(3, this.value)">  
        <OPTION VALUE=1> 
        1 
        </option> 
        <OPTION VALUE=2> 
        2
        </option>
        <OPTION VALUE=3> 
        3 
        </option> 
        </SELECT> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 

</body>
 </html>
```

The javascript function does not appear to be getting called correctly with the on change event.

Thanks and Regards,

Ryan Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ids for the rows in a sequential order and then set display property of the every row to display:none, except the first one and in the showUser method called on the each row while performing the selection, set the display for the subsequent row to display:block. You will get it working.

For example:

```
<table>
<tr id="r1">
<td><select name="users" onchange="showUser(2, this.value)" size=1> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> </option>
        </SELECT>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r2" style="display:none;">
<td><select name="users" onchange="showUser(3, this.value)" size=1> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> </option>
        </SELECT>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
function showUser(index,val)
{
 document.getElementById("r"+index).style.display="block"
//your code
}
```

**Edit Part**

Ok I am guessing what you want just change the size=1 to size=2 in the  tag. You will get the values within the dropdown list box itself.

**Edit on Jan17**
Hey change your function as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
    {
    document.getElementById("r"+(userNumber+1)).style.display="block" 
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi AmGates,

Thanks so much for the prompt assistance.

I have made the cahnges however the contents of my drop down list now appear outside the dropdown list.

What am I doing wrong, code to follow:

Comment: it's better to add an **edit** to your original question, and include further clarifying comments there. As you can see, it's kind of impossible to read code in a comment ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @ Ryan Smith Hey I have edited my answer check it out. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi @AmGates,

Thanks for the awesome assistance. I have edited the question to contain my latest script which I have simplied to try and source the issue without any luck.

I feel I am doing something silly, can you help out?

Thanks as always,

Comment: @AmGates, a big thanks man. working 100% now on the simplified version. I'll integrate back into the original code and feedback.

Thanks again, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post the final solution here and full code. Big Thanks to @AmGates on this one.

**index.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
  { 
  document.getElementById("r"+(userNumber+1)).style.display="block";  
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else 
    {// code for IE6, IE5 
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 
</script> 

 </head>
 <body>
 <?

 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', DBUser', 'DBPass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("DBName", $con);


$skusql="SELECT packcode,concat(packcode, ' - ' , description) as description from skudata"; 
$resultsku=mysql_query($skusql); 

$optionssku=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultsku)) { 

    $sku=$row["packcode"]; 
    $description=$row["description"]; 
    $optionssku.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$sku\">".$description; 
} 

 ?>

<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td width=393>Product</td>
    <td width=200>Category</td>
    <td width=150>Selling Unit</td>
    <td width=150>Grouping</td>
    <td width=150>Full Case QTY</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr id="r1">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint1"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r2" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(2, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint2"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r3" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(3, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint3"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r4" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(4, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint4"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r5" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(5, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint5"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r6" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(6, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint6"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r7" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(7, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint7"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r8" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(8, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint8"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r9" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(9, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint9"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r10" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(10, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint10"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
 </html>
```

**GetData1.php**

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'DBUser', 'DBPass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("DBName", $con);

$sql="SELECT Category, SellingUnits,Grouping,CasesPerPallet,ShrinksPerPallet  FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<table border=1><tr>";
   echo "<td width=200>".$row['Category']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['SellingUnits']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['Grouping']."</td><td width=150>";
   if($row['SellingUnits']=="CS"){echo $row['CasesPerPallet'];} elseif($row['SellingUnits']=="SHR") {echo $row['ShrinksPerPallet'];}
   echo "</td></tr></table>";
   }

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Thanks again to everyone on this site, really appreciated.